# Between date condition is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, compare

I have a data as below,

[image: Data]

Trying to run below query but returning 0 rows,
Below query should return highlighted row data as shown above.

Can anybody please explain me, what i'm missing?

```
select * from Flt_OperativeFlight_SchedulePeriods
where  
(
    (cast('2018-04-05' as date) between cast(ScheduleStartDate as date) and   cast(ScheduleEndDate as date) )
    or
    (cast('2018-04-11' as date) between cast(ScheduleStartDate as date) and   cast(ScheduleEndDate as date) )
) 
and CarrierCode='SQ' and FlightNumber='0004'
```

Comment: Your `2018-04-05` is 1 day before the range in the highlighted row and `2018-04-11` is 1 day after. Therefore, none of the statements are true so the whole where statement returns false for the highlighted row. To explain better, the first `BETWEEN` translates into: `ScheduleStartDate <= 2018-04-05 <= ScheduleEndDate` which is not true. Same goes for the second `BETWEEN` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *re-write* as:

```
select * 
from Flt_OperativeFlight_SchedulePeriods 
where CarrierCode='SQ' and FlightNumber='0004' and
      (ScheduleStartDate >= '2018-04-05' and ScheduleEndDate <= '2018-04-11')
```

Comment: Working absolutely fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because

```
'2018-04-05' < '2018-04-06'
and
'2018-04-11' > '2018-04-10'
```

As variant maybe it is what you want

```
select * 
from Flt_OperativeFlight_SchedulePeriods 
where CarrierCode='SQ' and FlightNumber='0004' and
      (
           (ScheduleStartDate between '20180405' and '20180411')
        or (ScheduleEndDate between '20180405' and '20180411')
      )
```

Comment: Maybe Yogesh Sharma's answer makes what you want.

Comment: I've also added one variant. Check it too.

Comment: got solution from Yogesh Sharma's answer. Your answer works too. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Flt_OperativeFlight_SchedulePeriods` 
WHERE ScheduleStartDate >= '2018-04-05' AND ScheduleEndDate <= '2018-04-11' 
      AND CarrierCode='SQ' and FlightNumber='0004'
```

Comment: This is an alternate approach but not an answer

Comment: Working absolutely fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to get *overlapping periods*, then you need this logic:

```
start_1 <= end_2 and end_1 >= start_2
```

For your query:

```
where  
(
    cast('2018-04-05' as date) <= cast(ScheduleEndDate as date) 
    and
    cast('2018-04-11' as date) >= cast(ScheduleStartDate as date)
)
```

Depending on your logic you might have to `<` or `>`